# Meteor Mongo database design user accounts

Tags: mongodb, meteor, database-design, meteor-accounts

I am building a web-app with Meteor and i am using the Meteor Accounts-password package and accounts-facebook package to make login easy. The user has some information tied to them like email & password, but i want to tie more information to them after the account has been created.

I know of two ways that i could do that and i was wondering how i should do it, since i can't seem to find any information about it on the internet.

Option 1:

I add all the additional information (like username, displayname and other stuff) inside the Meteor.user.profile object. This seems to be a bad solution since users by default have access to everything in the profile object and i have to manually deny them access.

Option 2:

I create a new collection, Profile-information, and store all additional data about the user and then tie it to the meteor.user object via some shared key. This also seems like a bad solution since i have to split my data like in SQL and not have all the advantages of embedded documents in mongodb.

This has been my thought process so far and i am at a loss of how to continue.
Which option seems to be the best way, or is there an option 3 that would work better?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why is it a problem if users have access to that type of information, which seems inherently public? Another option is to update the User outside of the profile object, in which case you'll have the choice of whether or not to publish the field.

Comment: @forallepsilon Can i update anything in the Meteor.user object? Could i provide a field, for example named 'additional-data' and then store all my data in a json object in that field?

Comment: As you may have tested by now, yes! However you might want to choose a different variable name. `user.additional-data` will have the dash interpreted as a minus. You could access it with `user['additional-data']`, but a better name would be preferred.

Comment: @forallepsilon Yes, it was just an example name. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @forallepsilon i found out that you could write any data to the user object you want. I previously though that the user object was locked, and you could only store additional data in the profile field.

I will store the additional data i have about the user inside the Meteor.user object by just creating additional fields.